# Rust book: Why does the match operator behave differently with this expression?

Tags: multithreading, rust, pattern-matching, expression

I was following along the rust book's [final chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html) where we build a simple multi-threaded web server, and once I finished it I decided to go back and clean up all the unwraps as practice. While I was doing that, I also decided to clean up some of the code and make it more succinct. One example of this was "in-lining" (or replacing a variable with the expression it represents, idk what the word for that is) an expression directly into a match expression:

```
let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv();
match message {
    Ok(job) => {
        println!("Worker {id} got a job: Executing.");
        job()
    },
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Worker {id} disconnected: Shutting down.");
        break;
    },
}
```

Turning it into this:

```
match receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() {
    Ok(job) => {
        println!("Worker {id} got a job: Executing.");
        job()
    },
    Err(_) => {
        println!("Worker {id} disconnected: Shutting down.");
        break;
    },
}
```

Coming from other languages, I didn't think that this would have any effect on the behavior of my code, since it seems natural to replace the variable that I only use once. However, this subtle change caused my multi-threaded program to turn into a single-threaded one: every single job requested from any client all got sent to 1 thread, rather than being spread across all threads in the thread pool. For example:

```
With the temp variable:
Worker 2 got a job: Executing.
Worker 1 got a job: Executing.
Worker 3 got a job: Executing.
Worker 0 got a job: Executing.
Worker 2 got a job: Executing.
Worker 3 got a job: Executing.
```

```
Without the temp variable (note that sometimes it's not always worker 0):
Worker 0 got a job: Executing.
Worker 0 got a job: Executing.
Worker 0 got a job: Executing.
Worker 0 got a job: Executing.
Worker 0 got a job: Executing.
```

I have no idea why this type of behavior would happen. I am going to assume it has something to do with the fact that `receiver` has type `Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>`, and something is going wrong there.

Here is the full function for reference. The purpose of this function is to create a Worker under the thread pool that contains an id and a thread option. In the original Rust book [guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html#signaling-to-the-threads-to-stop-listening-for-jobs), they use `thread::spawn` instead of `thread::Builder`, but I have confirmed that this behavior is the same either way.

```
struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(
        id: usize,
        receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>,
    ) -> Result<Worker, ThreadPoolError> {
        
        let builder = thread::Builder::new();

        // Create a new thread from the thread builder
        let thread = builder.spawn(move || loop {
            let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv();
            match message {
                Ok(job) => {
                    println!("Worker {id} got a job: Executing.");
                    job()
                },
                Err(_) => { // when we drop the worker
                    println!("Worker {id} disconnected: Shutting down.");
                    break;
                },
            }
        });

        match thread {
            Ok(thread) => Ok(Worker {
                id,
                thread: Some(thread),
            }),
            Err(e) => Err(ThreadPoolError::BuildError(e)),
        }
    }

}
```

Any clarification would be appreciated! I have a feeling that this is a `match` feature when interacting with Mutexes, but I wasn't able to find it in the Rust book.

Comment: Please provide more context including the code where you initialize the workers and send them jobs.

Comment: I suspect the `match` is promoting the `Guard` returned by `lock` to a stack local instead of immediately dropping it like the `let`.